# iOS Only Status Bar Rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, statusbar

The iOS project is designed to only rotate on certain view controllers.

This has only started to happen but when you rotate on a view controller which is portrait only, the status bar rotates but nothing else.

Loading initial View Controller;

```
ViewController *vc = (ViewController*)[UIBuilder viewControllerWithViewName:mainViewName];

self.appDelegate.mNavigationController = [[RotatingNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.appDelegate.mNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

LeftSideMenuViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideMenu"];

self.appDelegate.container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                              containerWithCenterViewController:self.appDelegate.mNavigationController
                              leftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController
                              rightMenuViewController:nil];

[self.appDelegate.container.shadow setEnabled:NO];

self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.appDelegate.container;
```

Comment: You should post some code